# Scattering theory on Schrodinger and Feynman languages

Tags: scattering, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

Recently I heard that both of "languages" of scattering theory (formal solution by method of classical scattering theory and its reworking by Feynman with his rules) predict virtual particles. But for first language intermediate states may be interpreted as particles which satisfy corresponding wave equations but don't satisfy 4-momentum conservation law; then, for second language intermediate states refer to functions which don't satisfy wave equation but satisfy 4-momentum conservation law.

May someone add some details to this text? As for me, there is so small information for understanding clearly. Perhaps my question contains some incorrect phrases, but I hope that it can be understood.

Comment: Hmm, the wave-equation is just the 4-momentum conservation law in momentum space, or, rather, the condition that $p^2 = m^2$.

Comment: @lionelbrits : I meaned Dirac equation, for example.